# Javascript - php, onClick checkbox function

Tags: javascript, php

```
//MySQL Query
while ($data = $reponse->fetch()) { ?>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $data['id']?>" 
            value="<?php echo $data['city']?>" 
            onClick="checked();" 
            <?php 
             if(isset($data['active']) && $data['active'] == '1') 
                { echo "checked"; } 
            ?>              
        > 
     </div> 
 <?php
   } 
 ?>

 <div id="test"> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function checked() {

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hello World";

}
```

I'm trying to see with javascript if the box is checked, but nothing displays in this code...

the function don't seem to be called.
Console gives me strange feedback:

```
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function localhost/:363  
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function (index):366
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function (index):297
```

I don't have so much lines and not working in those files

Comment: define `doesn't work`

Comment: Change name of javascript function, it should work, because `checked` is state of checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try renaming your Javascript function to something else, the name `checked()` doesn't seem to work.